# Extend a meteor collection server and client side

Tags: meteor

I am currently developping an app with the amazing Meteor platform. I would like to do something with my collections but I couldn't really find how to do it from the examples I have seen so far.

Basically I would like to display a list of items which contains their own countdown. Each items core data come from a collection. Each countdown starting times must be computed server side and not saved anywhere. Each countdown are computed client side and not saved anywhere.

I have a collection named "items" coming from my MongoDb db. At the beginning document in my collections could look like:

```
{ name: "My countdown"}
```

1) I would like to "extend" the documents server side in adding a computed property "startTime". A documents could look like then:

```
{ name: "My countdown", startTime: 40 }
```

I guess I need to use the publish method, but I don't really get how to extend existing documents that way.

2) I would like to "extend" the documents client side in adding a local property "currentTime", that i will update with a setInterval. A document could look like then:

```
{ name: "My countdown", startTime: 40, currentTime: 5 }
```

Maybe using a transform there but once again I don't really get how to extend existing documents.

3) I would likethoses 2 new properties reactives and so trigger some updates in the UI if they change.

So if i could get any starting points and good pratices it will be really appreciated :)

Many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can update a document of a `Collection`: Best practice is to do this on the server.

---

`client.js`

```
Meteor.call('setStartTime',
            [your_document_id],
            [new_start_time],
    function(err, val) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            // Successful.
    }
});
```

---

---

`server.js`

```
Meteor.methods({
    'setStartTime': function(itemId, newStartTime) {
        Items.update(itemId, {
            $set: { startTime: newStartTime }
        });
    }
});
```

---

This will set or update the `startTime` of your item. (Be cautious, as anyone with access to your JavaScript will be able to see your `setStartTime` call on the client. This is functional, but not secure.)